# Windows Authentication on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a application which is of web type. But here is the catch. 
You login to your windows machine with your username / password. Once the Application opens up it automatically logs in with the Windows Username and Password. Its how the way it is designed.

Now, I added Authorization Manager and gave all of it, it still says 401 error Invalid username and password.

It is a NTLM Authentication.

1. Can anyone help me with this?
2. How much JMeter supports NTLM.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add. I need to run and perform load testing using JMeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP Authorization Manager needs to be populated as follows:
Username: must match “User logon name” for Windows Domain
Password: Windows Domain Password
Domain: should be “what you see in Windows Security pop-up” as this is what real browsers do. If you are uncertain you can type a fully qualified domain name into that field you can just use “domain” or “domain.local”.
Other fields like “Base URL” and “Mechanism” can be left as is.
You can find the full example here: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter

Comment: Thank you. But I did "exactly" that. Still. It has so happened that it worked only once out of 100 attempts. So frustrated seriously.